# excel macro "object required" error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working for the first time with VBA and I got an error that I can't seem to correct.

I want to pass some fields from one Sheet to another. 
It gives me "object required" but I can't seem to figure out out so sold this...

My code is this:

```
Sub principal_main()

    Dim Max_rows, j, row_number As Integer
    Dim i, count As Integer
    Dim name_Row As String
    Dim morada, localidade, email, cod_postal, data As String
    Dim telefone, nif As Integer
    Dim escreve As Range

    count = 0
    row_number = 12
    name_Row = ""
    Max_rows = 23200



    For i = 13 To Max_rows
        If name_Row = "" Then
            name_Row = myWorksheet.Range("B" & i).Value
            morada = ""
            localidade = ""
            email = ""
            cod_postal = ""
            data = ""
            telefone = 0
            nif = 0
            count = 0

        Else
            count = count + 1
            If count = 26 Then
                name_Row = ""
            End If

            Select Case count
                Case 2
                    morada = myWorksheet.Range("B" & i).Value
                    telefone = myWorksheet.Range("I" & i).Value

                Case 4
                    localidade = myWorksheet.Range("B" & i).Value
                    email = myWorksheet.Range("I" & i).Value

                Case 5
                    cod_postal = myWorksheet.Range("B" & i).Value
                    nif = myWorksheet.Range("I" & i).Value

                Case 7
                    data = myWorksheet.Range("C" & i).Value
                    nome_row = Replace(nome_row, " - ", "")
                    For j = 0 To 10
                        nome_row = Replace(nome_row, j, "")
                    Next

                    Set Sheets("final").Range("B" & count_copiados) = name_Row
                    Set Sheets("final").Range("C" & count_copiados) = morada
                    Set Sheets("final").Range("D" & count_copiados) = cod_postal
                    Set Sheets("final").Range("E" & count_copiados) = localidade
                    Set Sheets("final").Range("F" & count_copiados) = telefone
                    Set Sheets("final").Range("G" & count_copiados) = email
                    Set Sheets("final").Range("H" & count_copiados) = nif
                    Set Sheets("final").Range("I" & count_copiados) = data_ficha
                    'Sheets("final").Row(count_copiados).collumn("B") = name_Row
                    'Sheets("final").Row(count_copiados).collumn("C") = morada
                    'Sheets("final").Row(count_copiados).collumn("D") = cod_postal
                    'Sheets("final").Row(count_copiados).collumn("E") = localidade
                    'Sheets("final").Row(count_copiados).collumn("F") = telefone
                    'Sheets("final").Row(count_copiados).collumn("G") = email
                    'Sheets("final").Row(count_copiados).collumn("H") = nif
                    'Sheets("final").Row(count_copiados).collumn("I") = data_ficha
            End Select


        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

new code, with some changes:

```
Option Explicit

Sub principal_main()

    Dim Max_rows, row_number As Long
    Dim i, j, count, count_copiados As Long
    Dim name_Row As String
    Dim morada, localidade, email, cod_postal, data_ficha As String
    Dim telefone As Variant
    Dim nif As Integer
    Dim escreve As Range
    Dim myWorksheet As Worksheet
    myWorksheet = Sheets(1)
    count = 0
    row_number = 12
    name_Row = ""
    Max_rows = 23200
    count_copiados = 13


    For i = 13 To Max_rows
        If name_Row = "" Then
            name_Row = myWorksheet.Range("B" & i).Value
            morada = ""
            localidade = ""
            email = ""
            cod_postal = ""
            data_ficha = ""
            telefone = 0
            nif = 0
            count = 0

        Else
            count = count + 1
            If count = 26 Then
                name_Row = ""
            End If

            Select Case count
                Case 2
                    morada = myWorksheet.Range("B" & i).Value
                    telefone = myWorksheet.Range("I" & i).Value

                Case 4
                    localidade = myWorksheet.Range("B" & i).Value
                    email = myWorksheet.Range("I" & i).Value

                Case 5
                    cod_postal = myWorksheet.Range("B" & i).Value
                    nif = myWorksheet.Range("I" & i).Value

                Case 7
                    data_ficha = myWorksheet.Range("C" & i).Value
                    name_Row = Replace(name_Row, " - ", "")
                    For j = 0 To 10
                        name_Row = Replace(name_Row, j, "")
                    Next

                    Set Sheets("final").Range("B" & count_copiados) = name_Row
                    Set Sheets("final").Range("C" & count_copiados) = morada
                    Set Sheets("final").Range("D" & count_copiados) = cod_postal
                    Set Sheets("final").Range("E" & count_copiados) = localidade
                    Set Sheets("final").Range("F" & count_copiados) = telefone
                    Set Sheets("final").Range("G" & count_copiados) = email
                    Set Sheets("final").Range("H" & count_copiados) = nif
                    Set Sheets("final").Range("I" & count_copiados) = data_ficha
                    'Sheets("final").Row(count_copiados).collumn("B") = name_Row
                    'Sheets("final").Row(count_copiados).collumn("C") = morada
                    'Sheets("final").Row(count_copiados).collumn("D") = cod_postal
                    'Sheets("final").Row(count_copiados).collumn("E") = localidade
                    'Sheets("final").Row(count_copiados).collumn("F") = telefone
                    'Sheets("final").Row(count_copiados).collumn("G") = email
                    'Sheets("final").Row(count_copiados).collumn("H") = nif
                    'Sheets("final").Row(count_copiados).collumn("I") = data_ficha
                    count_copiados = count_copiados + 1
            End Select


        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Where do you dimension and assign your `myWorksheet` variable? Put `Option Explicit` at the top of you module and then try clearing your errors. Consider `Dim myWorksheet as Worksheet`, `Set = myWorksheet = Sheets(1)`

Comment: Thanks, now it runs, it gives a new error (overflow), but this one must be because of bad coding. Thanks

Comment: it's probably because you are using `Integer` and overflowing it. Change `Integer` to `Long`. Also, notice that `Dim telefone, nif as Integer` dimensions `telefone` as `Variant` and `nif` as `Integer` and not both as `Integers`

Comment: done, but still giving me overflow. all my counters are long and `telefone` as variable

Comment: click debug when it gives you an error - it sends you to the line that caused it. Which line is it?

Comment: oh and remove the `SET` keyword from from `Sheets("final")`

Comment: now it gives a new error **Object variable or With block variable not set**

Comment: can you edit your question and post code you currently have?

Comment: you are missing a `Set` in the beginning. You need to change `myWorksheet = Sheets(1)` to `Set myWorksheet = Sheets(1)`

Comment: now it gives the overflow error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
Option Explicit

Sub principal_main()

    Dim Max_rows&, row_number&
    Dim i&, j&, count&, count_copiados&
    Dim name_Row$
    Dim morada$, localidade$, email$, cod_postal$, data_ficha$
    Dim telefone As Variant
    Dim nif&
    Dim escreve As Range
    Dim myWorksheet As Worksheet
    Set myWorksheet = Sheets(1)
    count = 0
    row_number = 12
    name_Row = ""
    Max_rows = 23200
    count_copiados = 13


    For i = 13 To Max_rows
        If name_Row = "" Then
            name_Row = myWorksheet.Range("B" & i).Value
            morada = ""
            localidade = ""
            email = ""
            cod_postal = ""
            data_ficha = ""
            telefone = 0
            nif = 0
            count = 0

        Else
            count = count + 1
            If count = 26 Then
                name_Row = ""
            End If

            Select Case count
                Case 2
                    morada = myWorksheet.Range("B" & i).Value
                    telefone = myWorksheet.Range("I" & i).Value

                Case 4
                    localidade = myWorksheet.Range("B" & i).Value
                    email = myWorksheet.Range("I" & i).Value

                Case 5
                    cod_postal = myWorksheet.Range("B" & i).Value
                    nif = myWorksheet.Range("I" & i).Value

                Case 7
                    data_ficha = myWorksheet.Range("C" & i).Value
                    name_Row = Replace(name_Row, " - ", "")
                    For j = 0 To 10
                        name_Row = Replace(name_Row, j, "")
                    Next

                    Sheets("final").Range("B" & count_copiados) = name_Row
                    Sheets("final").Range("C" & count_copiados) = morada
                    Sheets("final").Range("D" & count_copiados) = cod_postal
                    Sheets("final").Range("E" & count_copiados) = localidade
                    Sheets("final").Range("F" & count_copiados) = telefone
                    Sheets("final").Range("G" & count_copiados) = email
                    Sheets("final").Range("H" & count_copiados) = nif
                    Sheets("final").Range("I" & count_copiados) = data_ficha
                    'Sheets("final").Row(count_copiados).collumn("B") = name_Row
                    'Sheets("final").Row(count_copiados).collumn("C") = morada
                    'Sheets("final").Row(count_copiados).collumn("D") = cod_postal
                    'Sheets("final").Row(count_copiados).collumn("E") = localidade
                    'Sheets("final").Row(count_copiados).collumn("F") = telefone
                    'Sheets("final").Row(count_copiados).collumn("G") = email
                    'Sheets("final").Row(count_copiados).collumn("H") = nif
                    'Sheets("final").Row(count_copiados).collumn("I") = data_ficha
                    count_copiados = count_copiados + 1
            End Select
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks, found the problem with your help

Comment: @RicardoAlves glad I could somehow help!